# if you enable DKIM for a domain, can you send using mail servers which do not use DKIM?

Tags: email, smtp, spam-prevention, dkim, mandrill

I have two mail servers which we use to send emails - One of them is through [Mandrill](http://www.mandrill.com) to send transactional emails from a website.  Mandrill supports DKIM and we have enabled it and also set the required `TXT` records.

We also use an inhouse mail server in the office to send as well emails, and this one does not support DKIM.  Will this create a problem for emails sent from office appearing as not authenticated or spam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem.  Having the DKIM signature on your messages is a 'plus' as far as indicating to spam filters and other mail servers that these messages are valid messages.  But, not having the DKIM signature would not be considered a 'strike'.

Comment: I've tried sending emails from other mail servers and they didn't enter as spam, so I'm assuming this is correct. Thanks!